# How can I update a data with SQFLite in Flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, sql-update

```
   static Future<int?> update(
    String cariadi,
  ) async {
    var dbClient = await _db;
    return await dbClient?.rawUpdate('UPDATE $_tableName SET $cariadi = ');
  }
```

This is how I created the database

```
    void getCari() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> cariler = await DBCari.query();
    cariList.assignAll(cariler.map((data) => Cari.fromJson(data)).toList());
  }

 void updateData(Cari cari) {
    DBCari.update(cari.cariadi!);
    getCari();
  }
```

Try to connect value = key by creating a controller named CariController.

```
 final _cariController = Get.put(CariController());


 onTap: () {
                _cariController.update();
              },
```

Finally, I wanted to enable the user to edit the data entered by clicking on the edit part in a button I wanted. But nothing happened when the button was clicked.

What kind of code do I need to write in the database, controller and homepage I created so that the user can edit and update the data entered?

Answer (score 1):

**here is a reference :**

```
Future<int> update(Map<String, dynamic> row) async {
    Database db = await instance.database;
    int id = row[columnId];
    return await db.update(table, row, where: '$columnId = ?', whereArgs: [id]);
  }
```

https://github.com/DaymaManish/flutter_sqflite_crud/blob/main/lib/db_manager.dart